# Writing simple RSpec model test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

i am trying to write a simple User model test for RSpec. I have installed all necessary gems related to this but when I try to run this simple test code

```
# spec/models/user_spec.rb
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
    subject {User.new(first_name: "jon", last_name: "doe", email: "emmiemenz@gmail.com")}

    before {subject.save}

    it 'first name should be presentt' do
        subject.title = nil
        expect(subject).to_not be_valid
    end

    it 'last name should be present' do
        subject.last_name = nil
        expect(subject).to_not be_valid
    end
end
```

i get this error in the console

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/user_spec.rb.
Failure/Error:
          subject.title = nil
          expect(subject).to_not be_valid
      end
  

NameError:
  uninitialized constant User
# ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.
```

Comment: Is that the entire spec file code? You seem to be missing a `require 'rails_helper'` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `require 'rails_helper'` in order to get Rails to autoload the constants for you.

Also the spec is completely broken. Lets say you have this model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
end
```

And this spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  subject {User.new(first_name: "jon", last_name: "doe", email: "test@example.com")}

  before { subject.save }

  # ...  

  it 'last name should be present' do
    subject.last_name = nil
    expect(subject).to_not be_valid
  end
end
```

It doesn't actually work because you're firing the validations at `before { subject.save }` and `subject.last_name = nil` does nothing unless you actually fire the validations again.

Even if you fix that problem the spec itself is actually useless as it will give false positives.

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  subject(:user) { User.new(first_name: "jon", last_name: "doe", email: "test@example.com") }

  it 'last name should be present' do
    user.last_name = nil
    user.valid? 
    expect(user).to_not be_valid
  end
end
```

Run this spec and it will tell you that everything is perfectly fine. Then comment out `validates :last_name, presence: true` - when you run the spec again you would assume that it should fail because the last name is no longer required. But it's still passing because of the other validations in the model!

If you're going to unit test validations then test that actual validation.

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  # see http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/blog/2012/05/13/spec-smell-explicit-use-of-subject/
  subject(:user) { User.new } 
  # you just need to trigger the validations - not save it
  before { user.valid? }
  
  it 'requires a last name' do
    expect(user.errors[:last_name]).to_include "can't be blank"
  end
end
```

Covering all the validations at once will hopefully be done by integration testing.

I can highly recommend [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) which makes testing validations a lot less repetitive.